# present perfect in place of past perfect

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

This is from a novel "Confess" by  Colleen Hoover:

> I was too embarrassed to tell Owen **I’ve never been** to a bar before, but I’m pretty sure he could tell by my hesitation at the door.

What is the situation with *"I’ve never been"* here? Is present perfect  used because direct speech is sort of implied (I was too embarrassed to tell Owen "I’ve never been to a bar before") or is such usage just normal?

Answer (score 1):

If the author had backshifted it would be "... I'd never been to a bar".  But backshifting is normally optional, and in perfect tense contexts it is common enough not to backshift.  The meaning would be the same as "...I'd never been..." with the addtional implication of "and I've also not been to a bar from the time when I was talking to Owen until now"

Comment: After she hesitates at the door, they do go into the bar.

Comment: Or it could be a (pretty minor) error by the author.